# Power BI Total Sales Last Year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a Last Year Sales measure. Thus, the first-year value is zero and then it always shows the value of the previous year. I am using this DAX formula but no values are showing.

```
Total CWT LY = calculate([CWT Total], DATEADD('Calendar'[Year (Date)].[Date], -1, YEAR))
```

Do you know how to solve the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The DATEADD  requires a column of dates to work with, not just a single year value.

```
Total CWT LY = 
CALCULATE(
    [CWT Total],
    DATEADD(Calendar[Date], -1, YEAR)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach

```
last_year = CALCULATE(MAX('YourTable'[Cwttotal]), FILTER('YourTable', 'YourTable'[Date] = EARLIER('YourTable'[Date]) - 1))
```